# Even word-wrapping across multiple lines in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, word-wrap

Given a toy example window:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Width="200" Height="100">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="12">
            You do <Bold Foreground="Red">not</Bold> have a
            license to frobnicate all the things.
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The resulting output is reasonably nicely aligned -- although it would be slightly more even if the word "to" had been put on the second line (this done via a manual line break):

[image: Text size 12] [image: Text size 12 evenly]

Changing the font size down to 10 results in much less even output (again the second one done manually):

[image: Text size 10] [image: Text size 10 evenly]

Changing it down to 8 is sufficient to get it to display on one line, which is fine (although getting a bit too small to read).

Is there some simple way to request that it try to do even-line-length wrapping instead of as-much-as-will-fit-on-each-line wrapping?

I know I can manually insert a `<LineBreak/>` element or tweak the width or padding so that it happens to fit (this is what I did for the second image in each set above), but I would prefer something more robust to changes (eg. if I make the text translatable or include data-bound text).

I'm not looking for perfectly justified text, just a best-effort as close to the same width of text on each line as is feasible.